# Flutter FFI Failed to lookup symbol The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, dll, dart-ffi

i'm trying to integrate a native c++ library .dll to my flutter desktop app

this is the code from header and cpp (it contain different function but i'm trying to achieve this with a simple hello function)

the header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "lz4/lz4frame.h"
#include "fastlz.h"
#pragma managed(pop)

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace LSLib {
    namespace Native {
        public ref class LZ4FrameCompressor abstract sealed
        {
        public:
            static void hello();
        };
    }
}
```

the c++ file:

```
#pragma once

#include "lz4wrapper.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace LSLib {
    namespace Native {
        void LZ4FrameCompressor::hello() {
            std::string strMytestString("hello world");
            std::cout << strMytestString;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code from flutter

```
final path = absolute(r'native\LSLibNative.dll');
final library = DynamicLibrary.open(path);
final void Function() func = library .lookup<NativeFunction<Void Function()>>('hello').asFunction();
func();
```

and i'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'hello': The specified procedure could not be found.

 (error code: 127)
#0      DynamicLibrary.lookup (dart:ffi-patch/ffi_dynamic_library_patch.dart:33:70)
#1      LS4Service.initialize (package:bg3_mod_translator/src/infrastructure/ls4_service.dart:22:43)
#2      TranslateComponent.initialize (package:bg3_mod_translator/src/infrastructure/translate_component.dart:50:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      main (package:bg3_mod_translator/main.dart:51:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

i'm not an expert of c++ but i can't undestart what i'm doing wrong
any help? thanks!

Comment: I don't know Flutter or Dart, but the C++ function is in a namespace (`LSLib::Native`) which may complicate the lookup. What if you move the C++ function out into the global namespace? You could also try the lookup _with_ namespaces: `'LSLib::Native::hello'`

Comment: Btw, that header file doesn't look like a C++ header. Is it C++/CLI or something?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i have tried but without success
```flutter: Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'LSLib::Native::hello': The specified procedure could not be found.```

Comment: @TedLyngmo what i want to achieve is use this library
https://github.com/Norbyte/lslib/tree/master/LSLibNative
in flutter. I'm not expert of c++ , i have downloaded visual studio community to compile the .dll of this library but without success, the dll builds but i can't use it in dart

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't look like C++ so are you sure you can use dart with whatever language it is in that header file?

Comment: @TedLyngmo theoretically yes, if I had had problems opening the dll I would have already had the error on ```DynamicLibrary.open```

Comment: That's not necessarily true. Opening it without loading any symbols from it may work fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if it is not c++, how i can use it in dart? i can do anything?

Comment: _"if it is not c++, how i can use it in dart?"_ - I don't know. That's why I asked if you are sure that you can use whatever language it is that you have in that header with dart. First thing would be to figure out what language it is in that header of course. I would guess C++/CLI or something similar, but it's not C++.

Comment: Note that Dart can only FFI into C. If you want to FFI into C++ or something else, you need to first write a C wrapper for the C++ code and then FFI to your C wrapper.

Comment: Ditch lz4wrapper - as the name suggests it's a wrapper around some C code - notably `fastlz.c` and `lz4frame.c`. Figure out what that wrapper is doing - not a lot it seems except marshalling some calls into the C and write your FFI directly down to the C.

Comment: @RichardHeap thanks for the tip, I'm trying to figure out what the lzwrapper do, the fastlz.c and lz4frame.c are common C libraries?

Comment: @RichardHeap because as I can see these libraries are parts of LSLibNative framework that I'm trying to integrate in flutter, what I have to do to use these files (fastlz.c and lz4frame.c) in flutter?

Comment: Follow the instructions here (and similar pages for other platforms) https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/android/c-interop Use the "open source 3rd party" variant